# Calculating a grid equation

Tags: css, grid, yui

So I use YUI for pretty much all of my base CSS needs ... but I'm trying to apply the YUI3 Grids to a layout and I need to figure out what the formula to an equation is:

"The next step is to decide on the size of each "column" and choose the appropriate "unit". Remember, units sizes are percentage-based, so a bit of math may be required when designing with pixels rather than proportions. To create a 200 pixel wide sidebar, assuming a 960px layout, we would use a 5/24 unit ("yui3-u-5-24") for the narrow column, and a 19/24 ("yui3-19-24") for the main column."

How are they getting 5/24 for the 200px sidebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide 200 by 40. Now divide 960 by 40. :-)

[5/24 is 200/960 reduced to lowest terms.]

To find the common factors:
http://www.mathsisfun.com/greatest-common-factor-tool.html

Comment: 40 is the greatest common factor (GCF) of 200 and 960, which is what you use to reduce two numbers in a ratio to lowest terms. If the numbers were different, it might have been some number other than 40.

Comment: Thanks Brian... I hate math. I'm terrible at it and it frustrates me to no end... but I now understand the theory.